# Looking for cheap Xbox/playstation like remote controller for robots

Tags: radio-control

I saw some radio controllers for kids robots alike xbox/playstion game pads few months ago. But I couldn't find them by searching. I am looking for some cheap radio controllers for RC cars or other kids robots like console game pads.May you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using an inexpensive 2.4GHz RC transmitter?

I already had one for a WLToys V222 quadcopter
If you don't already have one, you can pick one up on ebay for \$5 to \$15.

I opened up the quadcopter and Identified the chips it used

- [Mini54 microcontroller](http://www.icbase.com/File/PDF/NUV/NUV00161201.pdf)
- [MPU-6050 Motion Tracking Device](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6050/)
- [BK2423 2.4 GHz Transceiver](http://www.inhaos.com/uploadfile/otherpic/BK2423%20Datasheet%20v2.0.pdf)

Based on this, I found the NRF24L01 which appeared to be compatible which I purchased on eBay for a whopping \$0.67US.  Add a \$15 Arduino Mega (or a $2 Arduino Nano clone) and you are all set to go.

After a bit of time and part in hand I hooked it up to the Arduino and I was able to control a servo using my inexpensive wireless controller.

[image: My Setup]

**SUCCESS!!**

My guess is that the protocol varies depending manufacturer; so, a bit of reverse protocol engineering may be required.  If you would like more information on the code and config for the controller I used, Up Vote this and add a comment.

[image: 2.4GHz gamepads]

There are also 2.4GHz gamepads available for a similar price.  Their protocol might also be a bit different; so, a bit of reverse protocol engineering may be required in that case as well.

Comment: Thank you mark,
But I am looking for a game pad like controller. something like ps2 controller.
Also about voting up, I am new user and I can't do this until have 15 reps.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  If you want a way to remote for a DIY project, using an RC transmitter is going to be cheaper and have better range than a wireless game controller.

Comment: I am trying to build warrior robot for kids and I think usual gamepads are easy and more interesting for kids to play with

Comment: There are also 2.4GHz Gamepads out there for a similar cost.  You may be able to use the same scheme.